# Phonegap + require Js

Tags: javascript, cordova, requirejs, amd, js-amd

How can we use Phonegap with require js ? I am try to add to phonegap using the require() method. My code is given below and all .js files are in the correct location. Please help me, it is able to load  phonegap via AMD , or Use Normal script method like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

this is my require config and methods

```
require.config({

           baseUrl: 'js/lib',

           paths: {
           controller: '../controller/controller',
           model: '../model/model',
           view: '../view/view',
           router:'../router/router'
           },

          /* map: {
           '*': {
           'tempName': 'actualName'
           }
           },*/

           shim: {
           'backbone': {
           deps: ['underscore', 'jquery','cordova'],
           exports: 'Backbone'
           },
           'underscore': {
           exports: '_'
           }
           }
           });


 require(['jquery', 'backbone', 'router', ], function ($, Backbone, Router) {

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        alert('hi'); // working
        navigator.notification.alert('hi'); // not working

    }, false);

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Requirejs and Phonegap tends to not work too well together.

The best way I have found is to just include the cordova script before your require modules.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/main" src="require.js"></script>
```

Check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16861136) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859651/is-it-wise-to-use-an-amd-loader-like-requirejs-with-a-phonegap-cordova-applicati). He gives good insight into some of the problems faced.

Comment: hi i have same issue and this fix works but camera did not woking , if we use require js , inside define fn iam try to call camera but not working @Garrett Hyde