# Are there any real benefits of using Require JS in a phonegap app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, requirejs, single-page-application

RequireJS has many benefits. Some being:

- To avoid a huge clutter of script tags in html file
- To be able to organize code in a modular fashion, i.e. helps or makes it a mandate to organize code in modules, giving it nice structure
- Prevents DOM to be loaded with unnecessary JavaScript, i.e. load only what is required, saving on memory and performance
- Load dependencies asynchronously, saving time and network bandwidth

Now considering RequireJS for phoneGap apps and trying to realize the above benefits I have the following thoughts if I do not use RequireJS:

In [phonegap](/questions/tagged/phonegap) apps we usually do a SPA (single page application), and all resources are available locally on the device.

In a sound JavaScript architecture (implemented for the phonegap app) everything is already modular and well thought out. We can include small modules (which are not more than 3 to 4 per page) required for a page on the page itself in script tags.

With garbage collection all non-referred JS objects/memory allocations are wiped out. Usually in a SPA no JavaScript (given a sound JS architecture) is too long to create a loading problem.

Are there specific scenarios where RequireJS really makes a difference especially in the context of phoneGap apps? I do not wish to use requireJS just for the sake of using it.

Comment: I think with some thought into what you're really wanting to know and a quick read on [Asking Guidelines for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) you could edit this question into a high-quality question.

Comment: Please see if this question now addresses specific problem of designing a phonegap using requireJS.

Comment: Much better, voting to reopen!

Comment: Rejoice. You are the only question today which I've had the pleasure of reopening. Keep it up!‮

Comment: cheers!! mate. I feel really good now :).

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859651/is-it-wise-to-use-an-amd-loader-like-requirejs-with-a-phonegap-cordova-applicati?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Priya!! But the link only discusses problems encountered using RequireJS, where as my question is more about why should requireJS be considered at all, especially in context of the points that i have raised.